# Bootstrap button dropdown child element's class is getting removed when clicked on other button's dropdown items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anujbhai/8powrbfk/2/).

What I am trying to do is use Bootstrap's drop-down menu instead of select boxes and utilize list items instead of option. The data that is being retrieved from selected list item and put into its corresponding button element is given a class of 'active-select' on a click event (shown in blue after it renders). Like this:

```
<li><a href="#" class="active-select">New York<a><li>
```

Clicking on other list item should remove the above mentioned class from other list items only within the corresponding button element. But the class is being removed from the selected list item from other button drop-down group as well. Like this:

```
<li><a href="#" class>New York<a><li>
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Use `.parent` and not `.parents` like this: `thisEl.parent('li').siblings().find('a').removeClass('active-select')`;

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/8powrbfk/3/

Comment: Thanks man... greatly appreciate your help!.. Though I feel stupid

Comment: In the long run, I'd use `.closest()`. With a `.parent()` you have to stick precisely to the DOM structure.

Comment: very true... thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are using `parents` instead of `parent`:

This line of code is the problem:

```
thisEl.parents('li').siblings().find('a').removeClass('active-select'); // parents targets all li's above `a` and hence siblings afterwards targets other drop-downs.
```

Instead use `parent` like this:

```
thisEl.parent('li').siblings().find('a').removeClass('active-select');
```

**Full working code**

```js
 (function () {
  var search_btn = $('.select-style').find('button.btn-inverse'),
   selectOptions = $('.select-style ul.dropdown-menu li').find('a');

  selectOptions.on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var thisEl = $(this);
   var getTextData = thisEl.text();

   thisEl.addClass('active-select');
            // Use .parent and not .parents
   thisEl.parent('li').siblings().find('a').removeClass('active-select');

   thisEl.parents('.btn-group').find('button[type=button]').html( getTextData );
  });
 }) ();
```

```css
ul.homeInputBaropenState { list-style-type: none; width: 500px; }
ul.homeInputBaropenState li { display: inline;  }
ul.homeInputBaropenState li a.active-select { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="select-Section homeInputBaropenState">
                <li class="select-style">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select City
                        </button>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">New York</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">San Fransisco</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Detroit</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li> 

                <li class="select-style">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select Type 
                        </button>
                    
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </ul>
```